# What (Hebrew) font styles are more legible in a digital reading?

Tags: font-recommendation, digital, readability

I have a desktop application which is basically a reader for different Hebrew texts. I know that in general some fonts are harder to read on a screen than others (both in English and Hebrew).

What Hebrew fonts (or font styles) are best for readability, so a user can read these texts easily for a long time?

Comment: I find `Block sans-serif` clear and easy for your brain to parse. It is described here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet, in the section *Stylistic variants*. 

Note: I can't read Hebrew, I'm just busy first learning the alphabet, and that font style seems ideal for my purposes. It is very neat and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found when printing a book for a biblical scholar there are Hebrew fonts for Hebrew text and we had to use a TrueType font named [SBL Hebrew](https://www.sbl-site.org/educational/biblicalfonts_sblhebrew.aspx):

[image]

It worked well in both digital and printed formats. If you'd like to test the font out here's the [font download](http://www.sbl-site.org/Fonts/SBL_Hbrw.ttf).

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across [this font](https://github.com/fontef/frankruhlhofshi), which seems to be visually pleasing to the eye. Note that I've only tried it in digital formats.